# View GNUPLOT figures from cluster backend

Tags: parallel-processing, cluster-computing, gnuplot, x11, pbs

I'm currently trying to run some quick diagnostic tests on some parallel code. I'm submitting the code through a batch system to the cluster backend through `.pbs` scripts. I'm capturing the diagnostic data from the executables but I would like to plot them using GNUPLOT.

Is there anyway to do this? I've ssh'd into the cluster front-end through an x11 term, so I feel like I'm almost there. Perhaps something I could do by passing the `- I` flag to `qsub`?

I'm also aware that this may not at all be the best way to do this. Any suggestions would be appreciated (e.g. can a `.pbs` script run the plot command on the front-end?)

Comment: I do not quite understand what's your problem. Can you run `gnuplot` on the frontend while the compute job is running on the nodes? Can you access the diagnostic data from the frontend at all  while the job is running?

Comment: I use gnuplot on the front end in our cluster, not problem with that. Are you ssh'ing with the -X option? Otherwise you'll only be able to use certain terminals.